# Register Horizontal bar for IE

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com, registry, atl

I want to register Horizontal Bar for IE. I create .rgs file and add some code.

```
HKLM
{
  NoRemove SOFTWARE
  {
    NoRemove Microsoft
    {
      NoRemove 'Internet Explorer'
      {
        NoRemove Explorer Bars
        {
          ForceRemove {355400D0-C4F8-470D-B767-E93C069A0123} = s 'ToolbarHandler Class'
          {
            val 'CLSID' = s '{**???**}'
            val 'BarSize' = s '23 01 00 00 00 00 00 00'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where can I get the value for val 'CLSID'? And. Where to specify the text that will be displayed in the menu?

Answer (score 0):

CLSID is class identifier and is a COM term you have to get familiar with to get further. MSDN gives a pretty detailed description in [Creating Custom Explorer Bars, Tool Bands, and Desk Bands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#clsid_registration):

> As with all COM objects, the Explorer Bar's CLSID must be registered. For the object to function properly with Internet Explorer [...]

about CLSID specifically and overall about other aspects.